# indexes on mysql joins for the join column and the where column

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I'm trying to understand how MySQL uses indexes for the join criteria as well as the where criteria.  If I do a join such as the following:

```
SELECT * from Table1
 inner join table2 on Table1.colA = Table2.colB
 where Table2.colC > val1
   and Table2.colC < val2;
```

How do I index Table1 and Table2 so that it is executing this query efficiently?

Do I need to do multiple single indexes on Table1.colA and Table2.colB and Table2.colC?  Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: You should index JOIN columns and columns used in the WHERE,so yes.

Comment: Try creating the compound index `(colB,colC)` on Table2. Then test performance and run `EXPLAIN`.  Then do the same with the index `(colC, ColB)`. Then, show us the results, please.

Comment: Unfortunately, I simplified an example on production.  The table I'm trying to make more efficient is a 73M row table that is 27GB big, and I don't have permissions to add indexes on the fly.  I would need to request our DBA to do this, and I need to prove beforehand that the indexes would help.  So experimenting wouldn't be an option unfortunately.

Comment: Here's the deal. This kind of query is often helped by compound covering indexes (look that up).  It's important to know the full query and the table layouts to suggest a proper index.  But one thing is for sure. You're doing a range scan on `Table2.ColC`.  Can you give more detail?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I index Table1 and Table2 so that it is executing this query efficiently?

Set your first column in each table as PK/AI (Primary Key/Auto-increment).

Then, when you need to join them together you can name the second column in tableB.colB linkToA or simple idA. That sounds a bit confusing, so here's a practical example:

You have a table of Students and Teachers.

**students table**

```
┌──┬────────────┬──────────┐
│id│    name    │teacher_id│
├──┼────────────┼──────────┼
│1 │Billy       │3         │
├──┼────────────┼──────────┼
│2 │Jeffrey     │2         │
├──┼────────────┼──────────┼
│3 │Sally       │3         │
├──┼────────────┼──────────┼
│4 │Frankie     │1         │
└──┴────────────┴──────────┘
```

**teachers table**

```
┌──┬────────────┬───┐
│id│    name    │age│
├──┼────────────┼───┤
│1 │Jan         │34 │
├──┼────────────┼───┤
│2 │Alexander   │26 │
├──┼────────────┼───┤
│3 │Steve       │23 │
├──┼────────────┼───┤
│4 │Joan        │56 │
└──┴────────────┴───┘
```

Now suppose you need to find students whose teacher is in between 25 and 35 years old.

```
SELECT s.name AS student_name, t.name AS teacher_name
FROM students s
INNER JOIN teachers t ON s.teacher_id = t.id
WHERE t.age > 25 AND t.age < 35;
```

**Result set**

```
┌────────────┬────────────┐
│student_name│teacher_name│
├────────────┼────────────┤
│Jeffrey     │Alexander   │
├────────────┼────────────┤
│Frankie     │Jan         │
└────────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: The query in the question calls for a range scan  on `colC`. Not sure this answer takes that into account.

Comment: Thanks @rick6, but I was asking about indexing on tables where there is a join as well as where clause.  What would the indexes that I would use to help with your example, especially on the t.age column?

Comment: @Steve No problem; I thought I addressed that by asking you to set the id on both tables as PK/AI? Primary Key is another word for "index".

Comment: Range scans benefit from indexes.  You didn't suggest one on the column being range scanned.